# Why am I not getting this to work, its not a nil value - Roblox Studio Issue

Tags: lua, roblox

```lua
local Room = {}
Room.random = Random.new()

function Room.generate(prevRoom)
    local possibleRooms = workspace.Rooms:GetChildren()
    local randomRoom = possibleRooms[Room.random:NextInteger(1, #possibleRooms)]
    local newRoom = randomRoom:Clone()
    
    newRoom.PrimaryPart = newRoom.Entrance
    newRoom:PivotTo(prevRoom.Exit.CFrame)
    newRoom.Entrance.Transparency = 1
    newRoom.Exit.Transparency = 1
    
    newRoom.Parent = workspace.GeneratedRooms
    
    return newRoom
end

return Room
```

This is my code for the ModuleScript, and here is the ServerScript:

```lua
local room = require(script.Room)

local prevRoom = workspace.StartRoom

for i = 1, 10 do
    prevRoom = room.generate(prevRoom)
end
```

So I'm running my program and it says my model (LongRoomRoof) has not got a valid part of my other model (Entrance) and then it points me to line 9 of the above script (Module for localRoom.) Please does anyone know how to fix this issue. I'll paste the error here:

> Entrance is not a valid member of Model "LongRoomRoof"  -  Server - Room:9

If you can please tell me how fixing this is possible Thanks!

Comment: So basically I'm making randomly generated rooms and the code wont work. Here's a link to the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z0g5sLZapqI

Comment: As you pointed out, the LongRoomRoof room model doesn't have a child named "Entrance". You need to add one for your code to work.

Comment: The thing is, it is added and if its not, then how come that it wont work because the code is the exact same as the youtuber?

Comment: The problem isn't the code, it is your Models in the Workspace. Double check that all your models have a child named Entrance and Exit. Make sure that they are spelled and capitalized properly.

Comment: Yes I was on the platform and checked. It all matches up

Comment: Do you have more than one model named LongRoomRoof?